# Fourth order PDE solution for vibrating beam rigidly fastened at one end and simply fastened at other end.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have Partial Differential equation in the form:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial^4 y}{\partial x^4} =0, \quad 0<x<1 $$

[Vibrating Beam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaXZT.png)

Boundary Conditions:
$$ y(0,t) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0 \\ y(1,t) = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}(1,t) = 0 $$

Initial conditions:

$$y(x,0) = 0.1\sin(\pi x), \ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,0) = 0$$

I have come up to the point where I have solved the boundary conditions and got the four equations:

$A+C=0$

$B+D=0$

$A\sinh(\beta) + B\cosh(\beta) + C\cos(\beta) + D\sin(\beta) = 0 \\$

$A\sinh(\beta)+B\cosh(\beta)-C\sin(\beta)-D\cos(\beta) = 0$

Not sure what to do next. I am supposed to find the Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $C=-A$ and $D=-B$, so

$$ A(\sinh \beta - \cos \beta) + B(\cosh \beta - \sin \beta) = 0 $$

$$ A(\sinh \beta + \sin \beta) + B(\cosh \beta + \cos \beta) = 0 $$

This guarantees a solution if the determinant of the coefficient matrix is zero

$$\left|\begin{matrix} \sinh\beta - \cos\beta && \cosh\beta -\sin\beta \\
\sinh\beta + \sin\beta && \cosh\beta + \cos\beta \end{matrix}\right| = 0 $$

which, after some manipulation, gives
$$ e^{-\beta} = \sin\beta - \cos \beta = \sqrt{2}\sin\left(\beta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) $$

You can solve this graphically as the intersection of the two functions. The first eigenvalue is $\beta_0 \approx 1.038415$. Since $e^{-\beta}$ decays rapidly, the larger solutions are approximately $\beta_n \sim (n+1/4)\pi $

---

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if your equations are actually correct. I tried solving for the eigenfunction and got
$$ X(x) = A\cosh \beta x + B\sinh \beta x + C\cos\beta x + D\sin\beta x $$

And the four boundary conditions give
$$ X(0) = A + C = 0 $$
$$ X'(0) = B + D = 0 $$
$$ X(1) = A\cosh\beta + B\sinh\beta + C\cos\beta + D\sin\beta = 0 $$
$$ X''(1) = A\cosh\beta + B\sinh\beta - C\cos\beta - D\sin\beta = 0 $$

In this case, the eigenvalues satisfy
$$\left|\begin{matrix} \cosh\beta - \cos\beta && \sinh\beta -\sin\beta \\
\cosh\beta + \cos\beta && \sinh\beta + \sin\beta \end{matrix}\right| = 0 $$
or
$$ \tanh \beta = \tan\beta $$

Since $\tanh\beta$ very quickly goes to $1$, $\beta_n \sim (n + 1/4)\pi, \ n \ge 1$. This is a very good approximation; the first zero is $\beta_1 \approx 3.9266 = 5\pi/4 - 0.0004 $

---

**EDIT 2:** For the eigenfunctions, we have
$$ X(x) = A(\cosh\beta x - \cos\beta x) + B(\sinh\beta x - \sin\beta x) $$

where $(A,B)$ satisfy
$$ A(\cosh\beta-\cos\beta) + B(\sinh\beta-\sin\beta) = 0 $$
$$ A(\cosh\beta+\cos\beta) + B(\sinh\beta+\sin\beta) = 0 $$

Note that these are actually the same equation (since the determinant is zero), so we can just pick any arbitrary pair that satisfies one of the above. For example, let $A = \sinh\beta-\sin\beta$ and $-B = \cosh\beta-\cos\beta$, then the eigenfunction is (up to a constant)
$$ X_n(x) = (\sinh\beta_n-\sin\beta_n)(\cosh\beta_n x - \cos\beta_n x) - (\cosh\beta_n-\cos\beta_n)(\sinh\beta_n x - \sin\beta_n x) $$

To show these functions are mutually orthogonal, we use the definition of orthogonality
$$ \int_0^1 X_n(x) X_m(x)\ dx = 0, \ m \ne n $$

The integral is a bit messy, but it should reduce down to some expression in terms of the determinant.

**EDIT 3:** The B.C.s are $X(0) = X(1) = X'(0) = X''(1) = 0$. Using integration by parts, we can show that

\begin{align} 
\int_0^1 {X_m}^{(4)} X_n &= {X_m}'''X_n\Bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1 {X_m}'''{X_n}', && X_n(0)=X_n(1)=0 \\
&= -{X_m}''{X_n}'\Bigg|_0^1 + \int_0^1 {X_m}''{X_n}'', && {X_m}''(1) = {X_n}'(0) = 0 \\
&= {X_m}'{X_n}''\Bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1 {X_m}'{X_n}''', && {X_m}'(0) = {X_n}''(1) = 0 \\ 
&= -X_m{X_n}^{(4)}\Bigg|_0^1 + \int_0^1 X_m{X_n}^{(4)}, && X_m(0) = X_n(1) = 0
\end{align}

$$ \implies \int_0^1 {X_m}^{(4)}X_n - \int_0^1 X_m{X_n}^{(4)} = 0 \implies (\beta_m^4 - \beta_n^4) \int_0^1 X_mX_n = 0 $$

since $\beta_m \ne \beta_n$, the integral must be $0$

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake. The second solution given is suitable. Thank You

Comment: you have any idea how to find the eigen function?

Comment: You just need to pick a pair $(A,B)$ that satisfies on of the given equations. For example $A = \sinh\beta-\sin\beta,\ -B = \cosh\beta-\cos\beta$. The conditions for $\beta$ ensure they satisfy the other equation as well.

Comment: I got the Eigenfunctions by substituting C = -A and D = -B in the X(x). I got the equation as A(coshb-cosb)+B(sinhb-sinb). How can I prove that these eigenfunctions are orthogonal?

Comment: I suppose my last comment wasn't too clear. I made another edit to the answer above.

Comment: Do you know how to normalize the eigenfunction that you have obtained in the Edit2?

Comment: Use $$ \int_0^1 \big(c_n X_n(x)\big)^2\ dx = 1 $$ and go from there

Comment: @ Dylan Why cn? Are we taking A common from the equation and so that $$ X(x) = A((\cosh \beta-\cos \beta) - B/A(\sinh \beta-\sin \beta))$$ And what do we substitute for \beta?

Comment: There's only one constant left since $-\dfrac{B}{A} = \dfrac{\cosh\beta-\cos\beta}{\sinh\beta-\sin\beta}$ is a fixed value. You can use whatever letter you want, I just called it $c$ because earlier I picked arbitrary values for $(A,B)$. As for $\beta$, remember from earlier work that there's no closed form. All you have to work with is that it satisfies the determinant as written above.

Comment: I am not sure I understood. The eigenfunction is $ X_n(x) = (\cosh \beta_n x - \cos \beta_n x) - \frac{B}{A} (\sinh \beta_n x - \sin \beta_n x) $ this? or $ X_n(x) = A( (\cosh \beta_n x - \cos \beta_n x) - \frac{B}{A} (\sinh \beta_n x - \sin \beta_n x) )$ ?

Comment: It doesn't matter since the answer will always be up to a constant. If you choose $X_n$ as the first line, then the integral is $\int (A_n X_n)^2 dx$. If you choose the second line, it's $\int (X_n)^2 dx$. In either case you'll get a value for $A$.

Comment: So, integrating if we found that $ A_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (say), then the normalized eigenfunction would be this? $$ X_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}((\cosh \beta_n x - \cos \beta_n x) - \frac{B}{A}(\sinh \beta_n x - \sin \beta_n x)) $$

Comment: Yup. You got it. Do make sure you put $-B/A$ in terms of $\beta$ as well

Comment: This is where I am having trouble. For every value of $ \beta_n $ the values of $ \sinh \sin \cosh and \cos $ would be different. Using MATLAB and Mathematica is not giving me the desired answer. For example I tried with $\beta = \frac{9 \pi}{4}, \frac{13 \pi}{4} $ I got different answers. How do I get through this?

Comment: Of course they are different. The coefficients are allowed to depend on $\beta$

Comment: Do you have anyone you can get help from for this assignment/project? I don't want to keep the comment section going out this long.

Comment: I do, but they too are stuck at the integration.