# Numerical Solution for the fourth order PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I have a PDE in the form:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial^4 y}{\partial x^4} = 0 $$
with boundary conditions

$$ y(0,t) = 0 = y(1,t) $$
$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0 = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}(1,t) $$

Initial conditions:
$$ y(x,0) = 0.1 \sin \pi x, \quad \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,0) = 0  $$

I tried substituting

$$ y_1 = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \quad \quad y_2 = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} $$

$$ \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = -\frac{\partial ^4 y}{\partial x^4} = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}) = -\frac{\partial^2 y_2}{\partial x^2} $$

$$ \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}) = \frac{\partial^2 y_1}{\partial x^2} $$

so,

$$ \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial^2 y_2}{\partial x^2}$$
$$ \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial t}  = \frac{\partial^2 y_1}{\partial x^2}$$

Is this correct? How do I go from here?

Comment: Your title suggest trying to get numerical solutions to a PDE, but I have no idea why you're trying to decouple it into a system as you've done. Can you state the entire problem?

Comment: This is the third time I've seen this equation. [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556626/fourth-order-pde-solution-for-vibrating-beam-rigidly-fastened-at-one-end-and-sim) my answer using separation of variables

Comment: @DaveNine I am trying to find the solution using Finite Difference method.

Comment: @Dylan Yes Dylan, that was asked by me. I am supposed to find two solutions, Analytical solution using the separation of variables and Numerical Solution using Finite Difference Method. Is the above mentioned method wrong?

Comment: I would say there’s easier ways of approximating a fourth order derivative by “normal” means

Comment: You also have no boundary conditions or initial conditions stated. If you want a numerical solution that kind of matters.

Comment: @DaveNine I apologize. I added the boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your username. I will say that this is nowhere close to the "finite difference method"

Comment: @Dylan That's not finite difference method? How do I go about it then?

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method)